# how make a branch ancestor of all branches

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have an application with name app1 and I have a git repository with one branch(master).Now I want to create new application(app2) .Now I want use master branch as ancestor of these two application because of many shared code and libraries.So I created a new branch with name app1,and I want to delete all code and libraries that is belong to app1,and let remain all shared code in master branch,So I don't know how peaple are doning this after that? what is the soulition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Branches*—or more precisely, branch *names*—in Git do not have ancestry relationships.  No branch name is the parent or child of any other branch name.  A branch name is simply a way that you have to tell Git: *Please remember some particular commit hash ID for me, while giving me some extra features.*

*Tag* names in Git work much the same: *Please remember some particular commit hash ID for me, while giving me some extra features.*  The key differences between *branch names* and *tag names* are the extra features involved:

- A branch name *moves easily*.  That is, the remembered hash ID today, and the remembered hash ID tomorrow, are likely to be *different*.  The kinds of motions that are "encouraged" (as in, that Git will do *on its own*, without any extra effort on your part) are what Git calls *fast-forwards*, which are a little tricky to describe.  But you're allowed to move the name around, from commit to commit, and people should *expect* motion.

  (Branch names also let you set an *upstream* and have some other features.)
- A *tag name* should, ideally, *always describe one particular commit, forever*.  As such, Git won't let you "move" a tag name without using extra effort.  A tag name can be used in conjunction with an *annotated tag* and this annotation allows you to store extra information, such as a PGP signature affirming—in a verifiable, digital-signature sort of way—that *you personally endorse this commit*.  This digital signature is not transferable, so if someone should take this annotated tag and make it select some *other* commit, the digital-signature-verification process will show that this is now a faked endorsement, not the one you made.

  Git can't *stop* you from moving a tag (with `git tag -f`, or by deleting a tag and then creating a new different tag that uses the *same name*), but people can and should expect tags *not* to move.  That is, once a tag like `v1.2` exists, it should name the same commit in that repository *forever*.

So your desire (to make a branch name an "ancestor" of other branch names") is already in trouble.  Things only get worse from here though:

> Now I want use master branch as ancestor of these two application because of many shared code and libraries.  So I created a new branch with name app1, and I want to delete all code and libraries that is belong to app1, and let remain all shared code from master branch ...

Git isn't actually *about* branch names in the first place.  Git is about *commits*.  Every commit is numbered, with a unique hash ID specific to *that one particular commit*.  This number is unique across *every repository everywhere* so that given any two repositories, if they hold the same *commit hash ID*, they literally hold the same *commit*.  These commits, with their unique numbers, are what Git is about.

Each commit contains a *full snapshot of every file*, like an archive (tar or WinRAR or zip archive), *plus* some metadata: some information about the commit itself, such as the name and email address of the person who made the commit.  (This information is easily spoofed, hence the idea of PGP-signed tags above.  You can PGP-sign individual commits as well, but there are tradeoffs that seem to make this a bad idea for most projects.)  *Everything inside the commit is read-only.*  No part of any commit can ever be changed.

What this means is that:

> ... I want to delete all code and libraries that is belong to app1, and let remain all shared code from master branch ...

You can make *new* commits in which the `app1` code does not exist, and put those commits on some branch.  But the *existing* commits, where the code *does* exist, continue to exist.

You can make a *new and different repository* (with new and different commits, which get new and different unique hash IDs) in which you *never store the `app1`-specific code*.  This is probably the way to go.

Having made such a repository, you can then choose whether to add, to that repository, commits in which the `app1`-specific code is *added*.  Git commits all *de-duplicate* any identical files, so adding code while re-using existing code takes the *same amount of storage* (except for some minor overhead) as storing *just* the new code.  That is, your `master` branch can be the library, and your `app1` branch can be library-plus-app.  But this may be painful organizationally.  (Or it might be the way to go.)

Another way to organize this is to have the library repository *just* be a library repository.  A completely separate repository, that you `git clone` separately, contains *just* the `app1` code.  To build the app, you clone *both repositories* and *build both*.  This may be less-painful organizationally (or, again, it might be the way to go).

Should you decide to use two separate repositories, you can then, if you like, *link* one repository to another as a "submodule".  I personally dislike submodules (to put it mildly) and would try to avoid this, but they do work, provided you understand *how* they work.  (The details are painful, such that many users call them *sob*-modules.  They really do not work the way people expect them to work at first.  But they do work!)

> So I don't know how people are doing this after that? what is the solution?

There is no single solution.  Git provides *tools*, not solutions.  "How best to use these tools" is a matter of opinion.